Problems running tests in WebStorm because of 'tsconfig.base.json not found' error
My WebStorm IDE is having issues running tests from the Web3.js repo. I'm not able to run or debug tests because the ESLint raises an error showing a File '../../tsconfig.base.json' not found error. The file I'm specifically trying to test is web3RPCProviders.test.ts.
I've tried manually setting the path for the tsconfig.base file and adjusting the root directory.
Any help with solving this issue and running tests with WebStorm?

Try running ESLint manually to see if there are additional errors:
> npx eslint path/to/web3RPCProviders.test.ts


It runs without raising any error
